# How to clean columns & convert to datetime using python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm parsing my data from JSON to following DataFrame, but I'm not able to remove the extra stuff from readingtime column & convert it to datetime format

```
                        readingtime                      deviceId  
0  {u'$date': u'2014-11-04T17:27:50.000+0000'}           1224EG12
```

I tried using replace, lstring-rstring but I'm not able to replace the extra characters from thr readingtime column

```
da2['readingtime2'] = da2['readingtime'].str.replace('date', '') 


data['readingtime'] = data['readingtime'].map(lambda x: str(x)[13:])
```

Tried loc as well but not getting errors

EDITED :

I want final readingtime to be
'2014-11-04 17:27:50.000 +000'
which I want to convert to datetime - yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mils +UTC

Comment: Which extra character are you talking about? can you please update the question with what is the current format you are getting?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, it throws following error - A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a lambda function to the column of the data frame, extracting the date from the dictionary via `x['$date']`, and then just take the date/time portion (ignoring the time offset).  As this is a 'datetime naive' object, Python wouldn't know what to do with any timezone adjustment. Use this stripped date/time string (e.g. '2014-11-04T17:27:50.000') as the input to `strptime`.

```
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'deviceId': {0: '1224EG12', 1: '1224EG13'},
 'readingtime': {0: {u'$date': u'2014-11-04T17:27:50.000+0000'},
  1: {u'$date': u'2014-11-04T17:27:50.000+0000'}}})

>>> df
   deviceId                                  readingtime
0  1224EG12  {u'$date': u'2014-11-04T17:27:50.000+0000'}
1  1224EG13  {u'$date': u'2014-11-04T17:27:50.000+0000'}


>>> df.readingtime.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x['$date'][:-7], 
                                                        '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')) 
0   2014-11-04 17:27:50
1   2014-11-04 17:27:50
Name: readingtime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: apply function throws an error  = DataFrame' object has no attribute 'datetime'                                                                                          Checked Pandas version, its                                                                                   Also dt.datetime should be  df.datetime (just a typo) right?

Answer (score 1):

try to use ast module. With ast.literal_eval() convert readingtime column into dict and then call key "$date" from the dict you've just created.

```
import ast

readingtime = "{u'$date': u'2014-11-04T17:27:50.000+0000'}"
da2 = ast.literal_eval(readingtime)
dat = da2['$date']

print(dat)
```

dat now is containing pure date string ready to be converted with datetime.

MarcinZ

Comment: IT works for a string but how do you use for dataframe? Type of reading column is obj?

Comment: Hi, you can convert the string into datetime object with 
d = datetime.datetime.strptime("2014-11-04T17:27:50.000+0000", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z") 
but timezone (%z) doesn't work properly in python2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that da2['reading_time] returns a dict,

```
da2['reading_time]['$date']
```

will return you the value i.e 2014-11-04 17:27:50.000 +000

Another approach could be:

```
start_index = da2['reading_time'].__str__().index(':') + 3
end_index = da2['reading_time'].__str__().index('}') - 1
date = da2['reading_time'].__str__()[start_index:end_index]
```

Comment: It works for a string, but I'm not able to implement it for my dataframe, but how do you implement it for a dataframe with one of the column as readingtime ?

Comment: I'm trying following code -                                                                                        I'm trying following code, is there any more efficient way ? for i in range(len(da2)): da2.iloc[i,3] = da2.iloc[i,3].__str__()[start_index:end_index]                                                                              Can you suggest better way?